# Raspberry Pi Camera Detached from Board

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I'm using the raspberry pi camera rev 1.3 camera and it has been working fine but then the camera detached and came off the circuit board. I attached the camera back to the circuit board and since then it has not been working. When i run libcamera-hello it says no cameras are available.
did the camera stop working when it detached from the circuit board or how do I fix it or do I need to get a new camera?

Answer (score 0):

A picture of your raspberry pi camera rev 1.3 would help to understand better the problem.

If i understant correctly, it seems that the camera (little metal square) desoldered from its PCB. In that case, if you want to fix it, you have to solder it back on the PCB. However, it is not an easy thing to do, as it is quite small and delicate.

It you have the money for it, I would suggest you to buy a new camera.